# laravel 6 session restart through each request

Tags: laravel, session

I'm working with Laravel 6, and my session driver is file. I've faced a **419|page expired** when I submit a form with post action and after tracing the codes I found out the session will restart after submission. Everything is good on local but on the server I've got this issue.
I tried with a raw Laravel project and it worked!

I've already checked directory permission, config/session.php,.env file.

## .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

## config/session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => false
```

Tnx for responding.

the problem is not because of CSRF token, it's session's fault. evry time a new session and new token will be started so the token thet I send from input will be checked with another token !!!

Comment: are you passing @csrf in your form?

Comment: yes I've already add this

Comment: You might try running `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache` on the server.

Comment: I've already tried them yet it not workes

Comment: i am also getting this issue on local server, how it will fix?

Answer (score 0):

If your form is in a blade, after starting the `<form>`, add a csrf field by putting `@csrf`. 
 
If you're sending the POST request from somewhere else (i.e. from some other domain/subdomain that is not project domain) you may want to disable CSRF check by adding it in VerifyCsrfToken.php `(\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php)` like this:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        // Place your URIs here
    ];
}
```

Comment: I have it, tnx.

Comment: nope, I mean when I asked The Q I had the CSRF token :)